# Создание расчетов

Tags: oracle, запрос

Есть таблица продажи, в ней столбцы "Количество товаров", "Сумма покупки" и "Дата".
Необходимо посчитать формулы **количество товара за 12 месяц / количество товара за 1 месяц * количество товара за 12 месяц** и тоже самое с ценой. 
Написали запрос:

```
select distinct p.chislo, sum(p.Kol_tov), sum(p.price_ed), v.chislo, sum(v.Kol_tov), sum(v.price_ed),
sum(v.Kol_tov)/sum(p.Kol_tov)*sum(v.Kol_tov) "Коэф. товаров", 
sum(v.price_ed)/sum(p.price_ed)*sum(v.price_ed) "Коэф. продаж" 
from prod p, prod v
group by p.chislo, v.chislo
having p.CHISLO = '31-jan-13' and v.CHISLO = '31-dec-13';
```

Этот запрос выдает результат, увеличенный в 4 раза, в формулу добавлять /4 не вариант. Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данной задачи.

Comment: Без уточнения постановки задача непонятна: 1) какова логика заполнения колонки "Число" в таблице - там последний день месяца или конкретный день продажи? Может ли быть несколько записей с одинаковым значением в этой колонке? 2) "количество товара за 12 месяц" - это "за двенадцатый месяц" или "за двенадцать месяцев" (т.е. за год)?

Answer (score 1):

Сложно понять задачу без данных.
Но как-то так:

```
SELECT '31-jan-13',
  SUM(p.Kol_tov),
  SUM(p.price_ed),
  '31-dec-13',
  SUM(v.Kol_tov),
  SUM(v.price_ed),
  SUM(v.Kol_tov) /SUM(p.Kol_tov)*SUM(v.Kol_tov) "Коэф. товаров",
  SUM(v.price_ed)/SUM(p.price_ed)*SUM(v.price_ed) "Коэф. продаж"
FROM prod p,
  prod v
  where p.CHISLO = '31-jan-13' 
AND v.CHISLO = '31-dec-13' 
GROUP BY
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Код не работает, не читается дата в select. Скрин таблицы приложить не могу, сайт не позволяет. А код самой таблицы найти не могу.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать даты до from  которые

Comment: Все равно не работает, выдает ошибку 
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Group by надо убрать

Answer (score 0):

Если исходить из того что в формулировке вопроса имеются в виду январь и декабрь, то можно просто получить две строчки с показателями для нужных месяцев и посчитать результат:

```
select
  ( -- считаем нужную формулу для количества
    sales_december.sale_count / sales_january.sale_count 
    *    
    sales_december.sale_count
  )                                                        as count_coefficient,
  ( -- считаем нужную формулу для цен
    sales_december.sale_amount / sales_january.sale_amount 
    *    
    sales_december.sale_amount
  )                                                        as amount_coefficient
from 
 ( -- суммируем показатели за январь
    select 
       sum(p.kol_tov) sale_count, 
       sum(p.price_ed) sale_amount 
    from 
      prod p
    where 
      p.chislo >= to_date('20130101','yyyymmdd')
      and
      p.chislo < to_date('20130201','yyyymmdd')
 )                                               sales_january,
 ( -- суммируем показатели за декабрь
    select 
       sum(p.kol_tov) sale_count, 
       sum(p.price_ed) sale_amount 
    from 
      prod p
    where 
      p.chislo >= to_date('20131201','yyyymmdd')
      and
      p.chislo < to_date('20140101','yyyymmdd')
 )                                               sales_december
```